# Windows 7 activation error 0x80070005

Tags: windows-7, encryption, truecrypt, windows-activation

I get this error if I try to activate my 2-month-old Windows installation.

- I have tried restoring default registry permissions and other things as officially directed by Microsoft - no change.
- I have tried adding **Network Service** permissions on the whole Registry/HKU - no change.
- The computer is not joined to a domain.
- Plug and Play and Software Protection services are running OK.
- I am using perfect Windows 7 keys which work everywhere else.
- I have tried using an elevated command prompt for the slui command - nothing changes.
- `slmgr /ato` in an elevated command prompt gives me the same:

> 0x80070005 acccess denied.

`slmgr /dli` says:

> Line 1333 char 5 permissions denied.

- I am doing everything as admin and elevated
- I can not run system repair from the CD since my system is encrypted using 3rd-party encryption software.

This should not be happening. I am using TrueCrypt for full system encryption. I have always used it and everything has always been OK on other installations - the Windows activation mechanism as well as all other programs do not even ever detect that they are all in an encrypted environment. It's always been transparent.

Comment: "I can not do any system repair from CD since my system is encrypted using 3rd party soft" - could this be part of the problem?

Comment: to add info to your question, use the _edit_ link under your question; don't add it as an answer. If you register your account, you will be able to log in and get access to any questions you ask.

Answer (score 1):

I have a couple suggestions.  First, I would talk to your encryption provider.  It may be that this is the cause of your issue.

If this doesn't work or this isn't the issue, contact Microsoft and open a case with them.  They will be able to help you out and since it is an activation issue they should do it for free.

Answer (score 1):

Truecrypt recommends that you activate before encrypting. I tested the theory a while back in a VM.  Activating an unencrypted XP, Vista, or 7 install works, then after encrypting it stays activated.  But sometimes if you encrypt before activating, it will fail.  Try decrypting the disk, activating, then re-encrypting the disk.  It will take a while, but it may be your only option if a restore is out of the question.  Just make sure you set the encryption software to wipe free space during the re-encryption.

Comment: But thats exactly what I did. As usuall, I have installed windows 7, all the updates and activated. I have encrypted it all after that. After 1.5 month, all of a sudden it started asking me about the activation.....

Comment: In that case, try running `sfc /scannow` from inside Windows (regular or safe mode) with the install disc in the DVD drive.  If you have whole-drive encryption rather than partition encryption, you may be able to enter the "Repair Windows" mode from the Windows Boot Manager after authenticating with the encryption software's bootloader.